# Javascript to format number as currency

Tags: javascript

I have the following code.

```
<select id="cage_options">
   <option>Please select</option>
   <option value="2,63330">option1</option>
   <option value="3,13300">option2</option>
   <option value="4,2000.00">option3</option>
</select>
<input id="cage_labor_estimate" disabled>

<script>
   function format(n) {
       return n.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
   }

   document.getElementById("cage_options").addEventListener("change", cageOptionFunction);

   function cageOptionFunction() {

       select=document.getElementById('cage_options').value.split(',');

       cage_option = select[1];

       document.getElementById("cage_labor_estimate").value = format(cage_option);
   }

</script>
```

I am trying to format the output in the disabled input box in a current format but get the following error:

> TypeError: n.toFixed is not a function. (In 'n.toFixed(2)',
>   'n.toFixed' is undefined)

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

John

Comment: because you have a string, not a number.

Answer (score 3):

You have a string and a string does not have .toFixed(). So need to convert that string to be a number.

```
cage_option = Number(select[1]);
```

or

```
cage_option = parseFloat(select[1]);
```